# Unable to authenticate FTP over public IP after router change

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, iis

Recently I switched internet providers, and so I was provided a new router (which is locked to the ISP so I cannot use my old router) with a new IP. After setting it up and port forwarding my server ports, everything seemed to work, and `canyouseeme.org` could see my open port 21. I changed my PC's static IP to match the router's range and I re-configured my IIS FTP server with the new IP. I can access the FTP server from within my LAN, no problem. However, when I try to access it from my public IP, things begin to fail.

The browser requires authentication, as usual, but when I put in my Username and password, the browser loads for a bit, and then prompts me again to enter my credentials. I an 100% sure I am using the right credentials as I can access the server from the LAN with those same ones.

I have tried it with the AndFTP app on my phone and the same thing happens. I do not understand why this would happen when everything seems to be properly set up, especially since I can access my VNC and teamspeak servers without a problem.

I have tried disabling the firewall completely, but no luck.

Comment: Are you accessing the public IP address from inside or from outside? Are you sure you're connecting to your PC's FTP server, and not to your router's?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Inside or Outside". I have tried both to use my wifi to connect to my public IP FTP server and my phone's Mobile data. I haven't had any luck. I'll look into the fact that I may be connecting to my router.

Comment: FTP needs another port for data transfer. Additionally when a client and a server communicate they include IP addresses and ports *inside* messages, on a different layer than you would expect. That's why crossing NATs and firewalls may be troublesome. Some routers can deal with these issues better than others, possibly with additional configuration. See [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie#Firewall.3F_What.27s_A_Firewall.3F) and consider less ancient protocol.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski What other easy alternatives can you suggest?

Comment: @grawity I was indeed connecting to my router. Unfortunately, the router I received is one that isn't very popular, so I need to figure out how to disable the inbuilt FTP myself since there aren't any guides online. Go ahead and add your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm a Linux guy and I use SSH-based solutions daily, so SFTP. I don't know how easy it is in Windows.